# How to find out which of the following are true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem $$-y''+(1+x)y = \lambda y,\quad x \in (0,1)$$ $$y(0) = y(1) = 0$$has a non zero solution

1. for all $\lambda < 0$.
2. for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$
3. for some $\lambda \in (2, \infty)$.
4. for a countable number of $\lambda$'s.

I am not able to find out the answer. On solving auxiliary equation we get $$m^2 = \lambda-(1+x)$$ How to proceed further?

Comment: The auxiliary equation method won't work here, because you don't have constant coefficients - and so your auxiliary equation has an $x$ when it really shouldn't do.

Comment: ok then what are the other options?

Comment: Are you familiar with Sturm-Liouville theory?

Comment: Is your first equation correct. there is no $y'$.

Comment: What is the context of this problem?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Why would there be a $y'$?

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

multiply by $y'$ and use

$$2\int y y'=y^2$$
$$2\int y' y''=(y')^2$$